# How to remove the space created between a sentence and a paragraph in HTML

Tags: html, space, paragraph

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/BqTUS/) is what I am running in jsfiddle.

```
<span style='font-weight:bold'>Summary: </span><p>This is a test.</p>
```

The paragraph is being generated by a custom html field so I can't really change that. I was wondering if there is a code that I can put before the paragraph that can remove the space between the 2 sentence. I want it to look like

Summary: This is a test.

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` tag is block element. If you want to display in a same line Set `display:inline` to `<p>` tag

```css
p{display:inline}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
 <span style='font-weight:bold'>Summary: </span><p>This is a test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm really new to coding and would appreciate it if you can show me how this is done. I tried adding what you said as a style, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm currently doing this in an inline method, Like how it is coded in the html section of jsfiddle. Is there a way to add the inline to that code. With the interface I have now I can't set the inline display to the paragraph tag without that code actually showing up as regular text.